# Server side rendering a single file component without vuex either router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, axios, server-side-rendering

We using Vue2 in a website, not an SPA, so we use single file components punctually to improve the user experience.

Ssr works with this code in entry_server.js, we can call this file from the command line for example `node ssr-bundle.js` or from an express APP:

```js
// entry_server.js
import Test from 'components/Test.vue';

const app = new Vue({
  render: h => (Test, {
    props: {}
  })
});

export default function(context) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(app);
  });
};
```

This is a example component:

```js
// Test.vue
<template>
  <div>
    {{apidata}}
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      apidata: []
    };
  },
  beforeCreate() {
    axios.get('/api/v1/versions.json', {params: {card_id: 274}}).then(response => {
      this.apidata = response;

      console.log('loadData!!!');
      console.log(response);
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

When we need fetch data from an API the component render ok but it doesn't show this data, the render doesn't wait for API request.

We found many SSR examples and doc using vuex and router for this, but, **how to make SSR with a single file component prefetch data from API and without vuex or router?**